# obfuscate or encrypt some plain text data in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, encoding, obfuscation

I need to obfuscate or encrypt some plain text data in my php 5.2 application.

I'd prefer a solution that would have input string and output string retain the same length.

This does not need to extremely strong, as there are numerous other layers of security in place.  Strong would be good, but this will just keep programmers/dba/support people/etc from accidentally reading the text from within the database.

key considerations

- **EDIT ADD** I'd prefer a solution that would have input string and output string retain the same length.
- only string text will be obfuscated/encrypted for storage in a database
- the php application will need to obfuscate/encrypt the data before the database save and will need to un-obfuscate/dencrypt following the database read
- this is a modification to an existing application
- only some columns will need to be obfuscated/encrypted
- only some rows will need to be obfuscated/encrypted, based on a Type field
- there are only a few load/save points to handle
- max column size is already determined for some fields, but not for others, but I'd prefer a solution to work within the existing size of the restricted fields
- **EDIT, ADD** the key will be probably be a composite of some Primary key info +uneditable fields

here is a sample database table and data:

```
int           char(1) varchar(24)              int      date
MyPrimaryKey  RowType UserText                 UserNo   DateChange
------------  ------- ------------------------ -------- ----------------
1             N       nothing special here     43       6/20/2009 12:11am
2             N       same thing, wow!         78       6/23/2009 1:03pm
3             S       fBJKg}.jkjWfF78dlg@45kjg 43       6/25/2009 6:45am
4             N       same old, same old text  21       6/25/2009 8:11am
```

The application would load and display rows 1,2, and 4 normally.  However it would conditionally (based on row type) handle the text in row 3 using this obfuscate/encrypt and un-obfuscate/decrypt logic.

Can anyone provide obfuscate/encrypt and un-obfuscate/decrypt functions code, links, and or pointer that would help here?

thanks!

**EDIT**
I like the simple base64 encoding idea, but is there a method that can keep the data within a fixed size. All methods listed so far have the output value larger than the input value.  This will be a problem for some columns, where the user can enter in 50 characters and it is stored in a varchar(50) column.

Comment: There's a large difference between encoding and encrypting so I don't understand why you treat them like similar processes. You have to first answer some questions: is the data confidential or not, do the developers have direct access to the database, if you can accept that a few developers can decode the messages, how is this protection scheme useful. If you're using base64, anyone can export the list and decode it.

Comment: @Wadih M., the given requirements for this project are to store this as plain text in the database, and limit user access to it via the application.  I'm going to go beyond that, with a minimal/simple obfuscate/encrypt functionality because I don't want to "see" the data when I work on the system.  With full access to the source code any of the other developers will be able to figure out how it is encoded, and they can if they want, but they probably don't want to either.  If they do, then no big problem, we're not storing top secret data.

Comment: If you can't trust the people who have direct access to your systems & your DB you either need to be more restrictive as to who can get at the systems or get different people.

Comment: @Sean McSomething, I don't want to see the data when I work on the system, and I trust myself.

Comment: Do you need the solution to simply be un-readable or un-hackable.

Comment: @pure_code, back in 2009, I just didn't want to see the data in the course of supporting the application.  This was in no way an attempt to secure the data

Comment: I have the same situation and I'm just going to do a simple rot13.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

for simple obfuscation use strtr() - Translate certain characters:
[string **strtr**  ( string $str  , string $from  , string $to  )](https://www.php.net/strtr)

**to encode in php:**

```
$readable='This is a special test string ABC123 ([+,-!#$%&*])';    
$unreadable=strtr($readable,' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ'
                           ,'¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ '
                      );
print $unreadable; //outputs: "ÕéêôAêôAâAôñæäêâíAõæôõAôõóêïèAÂÃÄ²³´A©Ü¬­®¢¤¥¦§«Þª"
```

**to decode in php:**

```
$unreadable='ÕéêôAêôAâAôñæäêâíAõæôõAôõóêïèAÂÃÄ²³´A©Ü¬­®¢¤¥¦§«Þª';
$readable=strtr($unreadable,'¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ '
                           ,' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~€‚ƒ„…†‡ˆ‰Š‹ŒŽ‘’“”•–—˜™š›œžŸ ¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª«¬­®¯°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþÿ'
                              
               );
print $readable; //outputs: "This is a special test string ABC123 ([+,-!#$%&*])"
```

you can easily replicate this logic in the DB if necessary (without looping): [Using a Table of Numbers, by Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum)

Comment: I really likes the base 64 idea, but I need the data to fit into existing database fields. The rot13() was fairly simple and kept the same size, but this strtr() is good enough for my purpose.

Comment: How did you choose or generate the strings you are using above.  rot13 looks simpler, why the added complexity?

Comment: @pure_code, from the manual: The ROT13 encoding simply shifts every letter by 13 places in the alphabet **while leaving non-alpha characters untouched.** Encoding and decoding are done by the same function, passing an encoded string as argument will return the original version.  this wasn't too much harder, but it makes it much harder to get any info out of the encoded string.

Comment: Yes, I know.  What I was asking is how did you generate the two strings.  I'm too lazy to count but it looks like you took ASCI (256 characters) and shifted 128 characters

Comment: probabily something like that, if you have a numbers table it is simple using CHAR, something on the lines of `select char(number) from numbers where number<255`

Comment: Very nice and simple string obfuscator method!

Answer (score 6):

How about [base64 encoding](http://www.php.net/base64_encode)? We use to use that to make SMS messages in our SMS Gateway DB unreadable by the developers.

Comment: oO You employ developers that are unable to spot and decode base64? (just kidding, couldn't resist...)

Comment: anyone can tell on the first sight base64 is used and decode it in a second. how does that make SMS "undreadable"?

Comment: Our concern was not to 'encrypt' just to make it 'not readily readable'. I was one of the developers and yes, I could have decoded any of it in a second.

Comment: There are some locks that exist just to keep honest people honest.

Comment: @Colin: you don't *have* to keep honest people honest; that's *why* they're honest! ...ugh. The vitriol's not entirely aimed at you, it's just I got sick of hearing this -stupid- argument from the RIAA and MPAA.

Comment: @David Thomas Actually you can "keep honest people honest". Imagine - you have to work with a database which contains private SMS messages and you, being an honest man, don't want to read this private stuff. If messages are stored as plain text, you won't be able "not to read them" because you can't turn "reading mode off" in your brain. Reading private stuff might make you feel less honest, therefore base64 is good enough to prevent this. It does not protect against dishonesty, but it helps to prevent  discomfort for honest developers who don't want to see private information.

Answer (score 6):

Try these PHP functions [convert_uuencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php) and [convert_uudecode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uudecode.php):

```
function encrypt_decrypt ($data, $encrypt) {
    if ($encrypt == true) {
        $output = base64_encode (convert_uuencode ($data));
    } else {
        $output = convert_uudecode (base64_decode ($data));
    }
    return $output;
}

$enc_txt = encrypt_decrypt ("HELLO DATA", true);
echo $enc_txt."\n"; // KjIkNSwzJFxAMSQlNDAwYGAKYAo=
echo encrypt_decrypt ($enc_txt, false); // HELLO DATA
```

Comment: Why did you ignore the word 'length'?

Comment: Functions do not require it

Answer (score 5):

There are a few options.

If you want very strong, you could look into [mcrypt.](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-generic.php)

But if it's only so working developers cant read the text without some work to actually do it. Then you could just [BASE64 encode it](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) or [uuencode it](http://is.php.net/manual/en/function.convert-uuencode.php)

Answer (score 4):

If you have mcrypt installed (all my current PHP environments have), you could use [mcrypt_encrypt](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php) and [mcrypt_decrypt](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php) like this:

```
function encrypt ($text) {
  global $key;
  return mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345");
}

function decrypt ($secret) {
  global $key;
  return rtrim (mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $secret, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345"), "\0");
}
```

which uses a global `$key` and AES (very strong).

Drawbacks are performance (in comparison to simpler ones like Base64) and that you somehow have to fix a key.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3):

if you're using mysql around version 5, then you don't even need much php for it, you can do it inside your query with the mysql string functions `encrypt(text, password)` and `decrypt(text, password)`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/encryption-functions.html

- `DECODE(crypt_str,pass_str)`

  Decrypts the encrypted string crypt_str using pass_str as the password. crypt_str should be a string returned from ENCODE().
- `ENCODE(str,pass_str)`

  Encrypt str using pass_str as the password. To decrypt the result, use DECODE().

  The result is a binary string of the same length as str.

  The strength of the encryption is based on how good the random generator is. It should suffice for short strings.

update: another possibility would be `rot13` ^^

Comment: I really like the same length string output, however, I'm not on mysql.  The rot13 looks promising

Comment: But...I think rot13 was a joke.

Comment: @ricebowl, but I only need a simple solution

Comment: rot13 was indeed a joke. rot13 is ALWAYS a joke ^^

Comment: rot13 is perfect if you need something to be un-readable but not un-hackable.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the mcrypt library.  It's not included with standard PHP, but it's easily downloadable and very commonly used.  Here's [a quick tutorial](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2001/07/26/encrypt.html) on what you can do with it.

It's best to make sure the key you use for the encryption is stored in a secure place, but if you aren't really concerned about security, you'd probably be OK just hardcoding the key into your code somewhere.