# SQLServer2008 : Obfuscation or scrambling

Tags: sql-server, obfuscation, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to obfuscate or scramble a column in SQLServer 2008 R2 without having to use encryption or some highly ineffecient custom made function that does substrings?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use encryption/hashing/encoding in your application and post the results into SQL? That's pretty standard.

If you *must* do it in SQL Server, you may want to look at using [CLR functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189876.aspx) within SQL Server.

Comment: we have a large set of data that needs to be inserted, the encryption is a bottleneck, scrambling in code is probably the closest we will get :(

Answer (score 1):

Not that I know of, encrypt the data coming in and out from the column with a 3rd party app like Java or .NET.  If you do it within SQL then the person who steals your backup can decrypt is since he has access to the function

Comment: And if it's a password, don't encrypt it at all, just store the salted hash.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this: [obfuscate or encrypt some plain text data in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043621/obfuscate-or-encrypt-some-plain-text-data-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Something to research a bit further here.

SQL Server 2005+ has the function - [`ENCRYPTBYKEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx) and its mate [`DECRYPTBYKEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181860.aspx)

EncryptByKey Params:

- key_GUID -  the GUID of the key to be used to encrypt the cleartext. uniqueidentifier. This requires you to have a `SYMMETRIC KEY` open on the server.
- cleartex - some text to be encrypted

Returns a `varbinary` up to 8000.

If you wanted to leverage these methods, you could create a column of type `varbinary` up to 8000, and save the output here.

I'd be interested to hear comments on real world usages of this function, and any anecdotes on its performance.